# customize oauth2 login page

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

We are trying to do azure oauth2 authentication for our app (Using code grant flow).

As per requirement we needed to show a customized page with our own branding to the user and not the standard azure login page.

Are there any solutions available to customize oauth2 authorize endpoint login page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding

Comment: Other than those things, no. B2C allows you to customize it more. You are using federated auth, so you can't always expect the provider to support customization, same like you can't customize Google's login page if you use Google auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding

Other than those things, no. B2C allows you to customize it more. You are using federated auth, so you can't always expect the provider to support customization